# UNION ignores column names?

Tags: mysql, sql, union

Why does

```
select 1 as a, 2 as b
union all
select 20 as b, 10 as a
```

returns

```
a   b
1   2
20  10
```

instead of

```
a   b
1   2
10  20
```

?

Is there a way to make `union` match column names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this solves your problem, but you can use subqueries within the `union` to put the columns in the "right" order:

```
(select a, b from (select 1 as a, 2 as b) t)
union all
(select a, b from (select 20 as b, 10 as a) t)
```

I realize the question is tagged MySQL, which doesn't support `full outer join`.  If it did, you could do do the `union all` as:

```
select coalesce(t1.a, t2.a) as a, coalesce(t1.b, t2.b) as b
from (select 1 as a, 2 as b) t1 full outer join
     (select 20 as b, 10 as a) t2
     on 0 = 1;
```

You *can* do this in MySQL.  This assumes that none of your values are never NULL:

```
select coalesce(t1.a, t2.a) as a, coalesce(t1.b, t2.b) as b
from (select 1 as a, 2 as b union all select NULL, NULL) t1 join
     (select 20 as b, 10 as a union all select NULL, NULL) t2
     on (t1.a is null or t2.a is null) and coalesce(t1.a, t2.a) is not null
```

Comment: "...none of your values are *ever* NULL"?

Answer (score 5):

> Is there a way to make union match column names?

Nope, selecting the columns in order is required with `UNION`.

Answer (score 3):

Column names are only pertinent for the first part of the union to deifne the union columns. Other unions will join in the same order the columns are given from the first select and often have differn names. If you want want to relate the first column to the second column, You can't. However you can adjust your second select statment to put the columns in the correct order.

Answer (score 2):

Union only looks at the number of columns, and their relative positions in the query string. it does NOT mix-match based on aliases or the source column names. e.g. You could have two completely different tables:

```
SELECT x,y FROM foo
UNION
SELECT p,q FROM bar
```

What should MySQL do in this case? return a single row

```
x,y,p,q
```

because none of the column names match? Nope. That'd be incorrect.

Comment: Thanks Marc, but actually I'd expect two rows in your example, and four columns (assuming `foo` and `bar` have only one row). IMHO `union` behavior is counter-intuitive. But I'm just a beginner. :-)

Comment: think of UNION as printing out the individual query results (2 columsn each in this case), then taping the printouts together at the top/bottom to make one LONG result set. you're basically making the DB engine to perform individual queries, then apparent the results together. you're note widening things, just lengthening